# Want to test for size of an array constant in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using enzyme and right now I have a const in my main file that I want to test the size of but I'm not sure on how to do this with enzyme or jest.

```
const menuItems = [
  {
    id: "loginID",
    name: "Login",
    link: "/",
  },
  {
    id: "eventListID",
    name: "Event List",
    link: "/eventlist",
  },
  {
    id: "listID",
    name: "List",
    link: "/list",
  },
];
```

I looked on google but wondering if there is a way to reference menuItems in my code? I have a menu that when open calls the menuItems const and renders the values in there

In my test file I tried:

```
it("renders three options when menu is active", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<EventPage />);
  wrapper.setState({ active: true });
  expect(wrapper.find(menuItem).length).toBe(3);
});
```

But obviously that didn't work. Any help would be great

edit:

Here the relevant EventPage code:

```
state = {
menuOpen: false,
  };

toggleMenu = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
this.setState({
  menuOpen: !this.state.menuOpen,
});
   };

       <Menu
        id="menu1"
        open={this.state.menuOpen}
        menuText="Menu"
        items={menuItems}
        //toggleMenu opens menu side panel if Menu is clicked
        handleMenuToggle={this.toggleMenu}
        data-testid="toggleMenu"
      >
```

Comment: With-out seeing your component `EventPage` code it is difficult to answer your question. But if you'd like to check the rendered elements you could do it like in the following [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-nightingale-hdl3k?file=/src/Example.spec.js).

Comment: Please see the edit above

Comment: Shouldn't a test like this be better for `Menu` component instead of `EventPage`?

Comment: Theres other parts to the page but i only posted the menu because thats the part i’m having trouble with

Comment: check what is being rendered with wrapper.debug() and assert accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could locate the rendered Menu, and then just check the length of its `items` prop

Assuming there is a single `Menu`:

```
expect(wrapper.find(Menu).at(0).props().items.length).toBe(3)
```